@paddle/paddle-js: How to use environmental variable for token?
I am a beginner developer and would like to understand how I can put my authentication token in an environment variable when using React.
I am using the nom package @paddle/paddle-js and followed the example text to export the Checkout function.
The example code employs useState:
const [paddle, setPaddle] = useState<Paddle>();
From my undestanding useState can only used in client rendered components.
However, I cannot only use process.env in server rendered components.
Can someone help me shed light on this?
I tried to use env:
token: process.env.REACT_APP_PADDLE_TOKEN
I expected that the variable would hold the correct value. However debugging showed that it is undefined.

Mainly you shouldn't add private tokens to the frontend applications. To resolve these problems you need a backend application where the user is authorized and the backend makes the call to the 3rd services without showing the token anyone.
If it is a public token, then it can be made publicly available. There are some options on how to store configurations. It can be run-time one, where you make a GET request to a server and fetch the /assets/config.json file. That JSON can contain your public tokens and other settings. A React Context can be useful to store the configuration and make it available in the whole application.
Configraions can be build-time also, like an environment variable. Every build system has its options. To mention some: Create React App, Vite. Sometimes these are stored in .env files. Don't forget to build the application for all your environments (Local, Development, Producetion) and try not to confuse them.
